# Detecting NON-mobile devices with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, mobile, user-agent

### Before voting for duplicate:

**Please read the full question below**. I explained there why any of "how to detect mobile device?" **is not a case here**.

### Question (and why it's not a simple negation of mobile dev. detection):

There are plenty of questions about *"How to detect an mobile device with JavaScript?"* (one of the best, if you are looking for it: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)), but I want to ask for something a bit different: *"How to detect **non-mobile** device with JavaScript?"*.

You might think that when I can make an mobile detection like this:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile
    |Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

     alert('mobile');
}
```

I can just put negation before the statement inside `if` and that would be check for non-mobile device. **Not really.**

The code above detects several versions of mobile devices. For all not recognized devices, we cannot be 100% sure that they are not mobile. **If** `userAgent` contains one of the typed literals (`webOS, iPone` etc.) it's surely a mobile device. **If not**, it can goes two ways:

1. It's not a mobile device
2. It's a mobile device that we did not listed (mistake, exotic device, device released after we wrote the code etc.)

So instead of negating the test for mobile device, I want to write a test for non-mobile (Linux/Windows PC, Mac etc.). That way, **if** the result will be true, I will be 100% sure that I deal with non-mobile device. In the other case - it's rather mobile, but it's only an strong **assumption**.

So basically, **I want to react only when I'm 100% sure it's non-mobile device**, and when I do not know it for sure, I don't want to take any steps (or I will assume it's a mobile device).

How would that formula look? It's safe to test against `Windows` (Windows Phone or something like that could also use that literal?)? What about Mac, Linux PC and others?

Comment: Sorry, deleted. my mistake.

Comment: @Avisho No problem. For any other people that would consider it as duplicate to any of "how to detect mobile device?" questions - read my the question - I give the arguments, why it's not the case here.

Comment: @PolGraphic Why do you need to detect if it's a mobile device? I was under the assumption it's still bad practice to alter your site based on browser detection and instead you should use feature support detection

Comment: @AeroX because in my case, it's not about a feature support but some properties that are impossible or very hard to detect without doubt. Just for example (but not only): pixels per inch, real screen size (in inches or centimeters). On PC I can assume that I deal with "acceptable" screen size (in centimeters) for my purposes. I cannot rely on px resolution (some mobile dev have great px resolutions and still screens smaller then standard PC). I hope I've explained myself, I don't want to make a book from it ;) P.S. I detect non-mobile device (not mobile) and other case I assume it's mobile.

Answer (score -1):

This is taken from [here](http://www.techumber.com/2014/01/single-javascript-to-detect-browser-in-both-desktop-and-mobiles.html):

```
var BrowserDetect = function() {
    var nav = window.navigator,
    ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    // detect browsers (only the ones that have some kind of quirk we need to work around)
    if (ua.match(/ipad/i) !== null)
        return "iPod";
    if (ua.match(/iphone/i) !== null)
        return "iPhone";
    if (ua.match(/android/i) !== null)
        return "Android";
    if ((nav.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") != -1 || nav.appName.toLowerCase().match(/trident/gi) !== null))
        return "IE";
    if (ua.match(/chrome/gi) !== null)
        return "Chrome";
    if (ua.match(/firefox/gi) !== null)
        return "Firefox";
    if (ua.match(/webkit/gi) !== null)
        return "Webkit";
    if (ua.match(/gecko/gi) !== null)
        return "Gecko";
    if (ua.match(/opera/gi) !== null)
        return "Opera";
    //If any case miss we will return null
    return null;
};
```

It's not very elegant but you can add/remove it to your preference.

A second answer, while I understand you are specifically looking for a NON mobile detection, you could also use http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ which has almost complete mobile device detection (Even the less popular).

Comment: It's not really a case. Your code detects the browser regardless of mobile/non-mobile. And using detectmobilebrowsers.com and negation is just more complex version of the code I posted in question. Still, I want to test literally against non-mobile platforms (Mac, Windows PC, Linux PC etc.) and not negating the list of mobile platforms (why? I pointed the difference in my question). Anyway, I'm not interested in browser testing (Firefox, IE, Opera etc.)

Comment: Perhaps something like this then? `var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";`

Comment: won't "Win" return true also for Windows Phone (mobile device)? Just asking, because I cannot check it right now.